# Wine error when launching setup.exe file of a game

Tags: wine

[image]

Refer above picture for the error. My NVIDIA drivers are up to date.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and what is the error no pictures please.

Comment: From the dialog, I can say that you must be having newest version of NVIDIA Drivers for your graphics card. But they depend on your graphics card also. Older graphics card cannot support the latest released versions of NIVDIA Drivers. Just as a 64-bit software cannot run on 32-bit systems.